# Issues with font and hyperlinks during Word to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, microsoft-word-2013, print-to-pdf

I have read several questions here but none of them helped me; most are from 4-5 years ago.

I developed a word document using the **Latin Modern** font, which you can find in several places out there and which should have a pretty "open" license (I didn't check though).

Now I want to get a PDF from it. So:

- I use the built-in PDF feature in Word 2013: word is not able to embed the font inside the PDF, so it gets bitmap-ed resulting in a low quality, big size file which is not really what I'm looking for. I know I could increase DPIs, but the resulting size is really unwanted.
- I use things like Nitro PDF Reader: same, no embedding.

It's like the `otf` files I installed are missing some "embeddable" attribute. I noticed they are very old also, but I haven't found some more recent release.

- From word, I use **Print** and select some virtual PDF printer, like PDFCreator: **the font is embedded** (neat when zooming, and very small size), but the file is totally missing bookmarks and hyperlinks, which is something I really need.

How can I workaround this?

I need to embed the font **and** have internal links in the resulting file (both hyperlinks and bookmarks).

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem several times before, I solved it by printing file (Ctrl+p) with virtual PDF printer. and exported another copy with built PDF feature in Office (Save As PDF). then I replaced All pages of exported PDF file with all pages of printed file (in PDF program like Adobe Acrobat). then saved it. Now I have PDF with links and fonts embedded.

Comment: Looks smart! I will try and let you know.

Comment: I solved by using http://www.derwok.de/downloads/ttfpatch/

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. To have quality in the LM Math font, the .otf file must be converted to .ttf, all problems when saving as PDF and losing links/hyperlinks, equation in image format when saving as pdf and disappearance of some characters such as parentheses, are solved with this conversion from otf to ttf.

Answer (score 0):

I get my answer, we need to take the right ttf on this website : https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman
as it is explain here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55787/latin-modern-roman-for-ttf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1215649)

Comment: I can't give the right ttf on your forum, I think. For me my problem was that my file of LM font was not a good one. It is not easy to convert one from otf to ttf. On this website it is dictly a good ttf.